# debugging java and flex Simultaneously in seperate IDEs

Tags: java, debugging, apache-flex, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I have a Java project that is being debugged in InteliJ Idea,
and contains some flex modules.

I use Flash builder to code and debug flex, and then compile flex code and copy it to my java project.
But it's very hard to debug both of them at the same time.
I can just debug them separately.

In other words, I'd like to find a way that IntelliJ (java modules) and flash builder (flex modules) could interact with each other.

Answer (score 2):

I use eclipse and flash builder, but this should be possible in IntelliJ too.

1. Start your application (server) in IntelliJ in debug mode.
2. From flash builder, launch your application in debug mode.

Once you have done this, you can hit the debug points you have put in both Flash builder and eclipse. I hope this helps.

Comment: I did this , but just intellij is debugging and flash builder doesn't catch break points .I thing  I miss something :(

Comment: Flash builder not hitting debug point could be for other reasons (you can google for fixes) . Do a clean build, restart flash builder, to start with.